# Power bi dataset update using power automate flow

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am trying to automate a process of button click in power bi report.
I have a dataset named Data with the ID and Flag column as shown below:
ID    Flag
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
I have a slicer and button in power bi. Below are the functionality:
Slicer : to select the ID.
Button : to update the Flag of the above selected ID to 1 in the power bi dataset itself
Is there any possible way to achieve this using power automate flows or other approach can also be suggested.

Expectation:
Slicer: selected ID 1
After Button click, the table should look like the below:
ID    Flag
1      1
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0

Comment: Oh lord ...!  Please ... add some screenshots or something.  Apologies but I find that ridiculously hard to follow.